# xUnit Test Case of a WebAPI integrated with an Identity Server - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3, xunit.net, web-api-testing

I tried to write a `xUnit` Test Case for a Web API Controller which has an Authorize tag and its integrated with an `Identity Server 3`. I tried to mock up the `OWIN` Context but I failed.

The C# WEB API Controller Method is

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public string GetWelcomeMessage(string str) {
    if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(str)) {
        return "Welcome " + str + "!";
    } else {
        return "Welcome Guest !";
    }
}
```

StartUp C# Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:1000/core",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "PMS" } });

        app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
    }
}
```

Kindly assist me how to write a Test Method for the above said Controller Method.

Comment: Not answer, but the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939813/11635

Comment: you could stand up a full server and test the full integration (without an IIS dep): http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2015/01/07/testing-an-asp-net-webapi-app-in-memory/

Comment: see also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864725/ASP-NET-Understanding-OWIN-Katana-and-the-Middlewa