# How to write Unit Test for code that uses IOwinContext extension methods

Tags: nunit, identityserver3

IdentityServer3 has a lot extension methods, which are nice to have. The problem arises when trying to unit test the code that has some of these IOwinContext extension method calls like: GetIdentityServerHost(), GetIdentityServerBasePath() etc. from this [class](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/Extensions/InternalOwinExtensions.cs).

Even after mocking HttpContext and being able to get a OwinContext instance, I still get errors because since everything is a mock, so internal dependencies (e.g Autofac based) are not resolved.

Below is a unit test error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable'1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions.InternalOwinExtensions.ResolveDependency(IOwinContext context, Type type) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Extensions\InternalOwinExtensions.cs:line 78
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions.InternalOwinExtensions.ResolveDependency[T](IOwinContext context) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Extensions\InternalOwinExtensions.cs:line 70
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions.OwinEnvironmentExtensions.GetIdentityServerIssuerUri(IDictionary'2 env) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Extensions\OwinEnvironmentExtensions.cs:line 672
```

**Has anyone got around this, or you just skip writing test for such classes?** - Here come the bullets! I know its bad to skip tests, but I am on the verge of giving up trying.

Comment: Extension methods make mocking tricky, because when setting up or verifying a call to a mock, you have to mock what is *actually* called on the dependency. Depending what mocking framework you're using (no tag to give me a clue) there are probably ways to work out what the actual call is; or you can look at the definition of the extension method.

Comment: I am using Ninject for my host, but identityserver3 internally uses Autofac. I have no control over it.

Comment: Neither of those is a mocking framework. For example, if you were using [tag:moq] I might point you at something like this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919939/unable-to-mock-owin-context-in-c-sharp-web-api-rest-service-unit-test

Comment: Yes I use Moq with NUnit

Comment: That link is about WebApis. Mine is an MVC solution so i don't have that Set OwinContext option. Nevertheless my OwinContext is not null so that is not my issue. My issue is that my code calls an owin extension method inside an external library. That method internally has an autofac dependency, which obviously is uninitialized because I don't know how to inject dependency into a http pipeline inside a unit test.